# How to add e-mails in 2 different databases in drupal 7

Tags: webforms, emails

I used drupal 7.10 to built my website and i used 2 modules, the first is the webform to build the membership form, and the simplenews to write and send newsletter to users.

Anyone could subscribe in the newsletter even if it is not a member by enter her\his email in a newsletter subscribtion block in the home bage.

but what i wnat is that, when a user becomes a member he will join the newsletter service by adding his e-mail directly to a newsletter database, he don't need to enter his email in the newsletter subscribtion block agine.

How can i do this???

Answer (score 2):

You have an option in Simplenews to subscribe the user on registration since 6-x.2.x : http://drupal.org/node/658242.

Comment: Than you for your response, dose it work with membership form (using webform module)??. in my site the user don't need to log in to the site.

Comment: You'll have to ask for this in one issue queue or the other (Webform or Simplenews).